# How to set the value for textbox with javascript on an ASP.NET

Tags: javascript, c#, jquery, asp.net, google-maps

I need to set up asp textbox with a value from javascript input.

i have here:

```
<td ><asp:TextBox ID="AddressTextBox" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("Address") %>' ClientIDMode="Static" />
                    <asp:RequiredFieldValidator ID="RequiredFieldValidator1" runat="server" 
                        ControlToValidate="AddressTextBox" ErrorMessage="*" 
                        ValidationGroup="InsertCustomer" SetFocusOnError="True"></asp:RequiredFieldValidator>
</td>
```

I use autocomplete address form from [here](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/places-autocomplete-addressform)

so i placed this to the javascript code:

```
var src = document.getElementById("autocomplete");
var dst = document.getElementById("AddressTextBox");
```

and this to function fillInAddress()  funcion:

```
function fillInAddress() {
        // Get the place details from the autocomplete object.
        var place = autocomplete.getPlace();

        for (var component in componentForm) {
          document.getElementById(component).value = '';
          document.getElementById(component).disabled = false;

        dst.value = src.value;
        }
```

Im trying to get the full address from the autocomplete to the AddressTextBox field as soon as the address is selected.

But im getting an error that AddressTextBox "The name 'AddressTextBox' does not exist in the current context"

Any ideas? thanks.

Comment: That error must be from the server-side, JavaScript doesn't write errors like that.

Comment: Without seeing the whole code `AddressTextBox` is probably a child control of another control, you'd have to loop through each controls controls to find based on id name.

Answer (score 1):

AddressTextBox is server control so the ID might be changed.
 Try as:

```
var dst = document.getElementById("<%=AddressTextBox.ClientID%>").value;
```

This may resolve your error.

Comment: Still the same:


Compiler Error Message: CS0103: The name 'AddressTextBox' does not exist in the current context

Source Error:

Line 283:         var src = document.getElementById("autocomplete");
Line 284:         var dst = document.getElementById("<%=AddressTextBox.ClientID%>").value;

Comment: I am sending a sample solution, check whether it solves your problem

Answer (score 0):

Just run this working piece of code, this might help you:

```
<%@ Page Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeBehind="Default.aspx.cs" Inherits="WebApplication1.Default" %>

<!DOCTYPE html>

<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head runat="server">
    <title></title>

    <script type="text/javascript">
        function setValues()
        {
            document.getElementById('dest').value=document.getElementById('src').value;
        }
    </script>
</head>
<body>
    <form id="form1" runat="server">
        <div>
            <asp:TextBox ID="src" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
            <asp:TextBox ID="dest" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
            <input type="button" value="Set Value" onclick="setValues()" />
        </div>
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

Now you can customise the solution as per your requirement.

Answer (score 0):

It looks that I made it work. I just added the following:

```
document.getElementById('ctl00_maincontent_FormView1_AddressTextBox').value = document.getElementById('autocomplete').value;
```

into  function `fillInAddress()`